# Multiple source management having varying structures

Tags: database-design, etl

I have a design problem which can have multiple options.
we have multiple sources from which we extract data :
src1,src2,src3
These sources present their information about same content in different fashion,
lets say src1 has table1 with 3 fields(f1,f2,f3) 
,src2 has table1 with fields(fc1,fc2,fc3,fc4,fc5) etc

what i want is a configurable output(where configuration requires least possible effort) and have a uniform structure at other end.This configuration will let me decide the src,table,fiels that i want to select for the next upload.

My solution includes following design decision:

- maintain a meta area where you need to have information on each data source.This meta area will contain the super set of all the proposed structures  supported by sources.
- for each sources now get a working staging area which maps from this initial meta area.

This will solve two problems,
1.Tracking of all the sources
2.uniform listing of sources

I would like further suggestions on this design.

I have looked in though some sources but no relevant process is mentioned.

Avoiding Data Quality Pitfalls when Reconciling Multiple Sources :
[http://www.blue-granite.com/blog/bid/313445/Avoiding-Data-Quality-Pitfalls-when-Reconciling-Multiple-Sources]

Answer (score 0):

We solved a very similar situation using some metadata tables. The table looks something like metadata_tbl(type, property, value, enabled). 
Type will define what kind of property this is.
Property can be anything for which the values can change.
Value will actually contain the correct value for any active scenario which is characterized by the enabled flag. 
Based on your requirements, you can create a rule if more than one records can have enabled flag set to Y or not.

Now for any scenario, all you need to do is search for the particular type and property and pick the active value.

E.g. you want to map a column x of the source table A to column Y in the target table t, you can create a record in the metadata table

```
Type      Property    Value  Enabled
ColMap    t.y         x      Y
```

Later if the map changes, all you need to do is change the mapping here and your ETL need not be changed at all.